# Erro ao utilizar o AutoMapper " Class Not Found"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Estou estudando a utilização do `AutoMapper`, porém recebo um erro em meu projeto.

> Versão do AutoMapper: v3.3.1

Adicionei o `Config` em meu `Global.asax, ficando assim:`

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
        }
```

O meu `AutoMapperConfig` está desta forma:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterMappings()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappingProfile>();
                cfg.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile>();
            });
        }
    }
```

Minha classe `DomainToViewModelMappingProfile` está desta forma:

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public override string ProfileName
        {
            get { return "DomainToViewModelMappings"; }
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Pessoa, PessoaViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Endereco, EnderecoViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Pessoa, PessoaEnderecoViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Endereco, PessoaEnderecoViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

e a `ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile` está assim:

```
public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public override string ProfileName
        {
            get { return "ViewModelToDomainMappings"; }
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<PessoaViewModel, Pessoa>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<EnderecoViewModel, Endereco>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<PessoaEnderecoViewModel, Pessoa>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<PessoaEnderecoViewModel, Endereco>();
        }
    }
```

Ao "mapear" a classe em meu `AppService` assim:

```
 public void Adicionar(PessoaEnderecoViewModel pessoaEnderecoViewModel)
    {

        var pessoa = Mapper.Map<PessoaEnderecoViewModel, Pessoa>(pessoaEnderecoViewModel);
        var endereco = Mapper.Map<PessoaEnderecoViewModel, Endereco>(pessoaEnderecoViewModel);

        pessoa.Enderecos.Add(endereco);
        _pessoaRepository.Add(pessoa);
    }
```

Ao debugar, quando chego nesta parte  `var pessoa = Mapper.Map(pessoaEnderecoViewModel);` recebo o seguinte erro:

> Mapper.cs not found

```
Locating source for 'c:\dev\AutoMapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {28 13 88 2d fa c bf 90 0 c9 9c 25 64 11 3d 36}
The file 'c:\dev\AutoMapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'c:\dev\AutoMapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'c:\dev\AutoMapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src\vccorlib\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: c:\dev\AutoMapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\dev\AutoMapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs'.
```

E aparece a opção para localizar o arquivo Mapper.cs.

Tentei seguir o exemplo do [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28888271), porém não ajudou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui aqui, estava verificando o erro no lugar errado.

O problema estava em minha classe  `Pessoa`. Eu possuo uma `ICollection` .
Ao iniciar ela no construtor, o mesmo funcionou perfeitamente.

```
public Pessoa()
        {
            Enderecos = new List<Endereco>();
        }
```